# How to configure CMake so that the generated Visual Studio project finds the executable?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to set up a project with CMake in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows. The CMakeLists.txt is pretty simple. I am just adding an executable with source files and I specify the linker language to C++.

Then I run cmake in my build_64 folder and I get the generated VS solution containing ALL_BUILD, ZERO_CHECK and my actual project of course. I set it to be my start project and try to run it but then I get this error message:

*Unable to start program 'C:\Users...\Documents\MyProject\build_64\Debug\Project1.exe'.
The system is unable to find the specified file.*

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(MyProject)

# create Project1
set(PROJECT1_SOURCES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Project1/src/)
add_executable(Project1 ${PROJECT1_SOURCES})
set_target_properties(Project1 PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

cmake command:

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
```

Why can Visual Studio not find my executable? And how can I configure it so that Visual Studio finds it?

Here is my folder structure:

```
MyProject
   - build_64
       - ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
       ...
       - MyProject.sln
       - Project1.vcxproj
       - ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj
    - Project1
       - src
CMakeLists.txt
CMakeSettings.json
```

Comment: `set(PROJECT1_SOURCES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Project1/src/)` is wrong. You need to list every cpp file. Something like `set(PROJECT1_SOURCES ./src/main.cpp  ./src/myclass.cpp )` For visual studio you should also list headers so that they show up in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. Should I add the headers to the include directories seperately or with the cpp files in the PROJECT1_SOURCES as well?

Comment: For projects of more than 5 files I create separate variables.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Cmake does not generate executable - cmake creates a build system for you. Then you need to build your project in VS or inside the command line.
If you need to address some executable and later call it here is a snippet for you :

```
find_program(THRIFT_COMPILER NAMES thrift thrift.exe HINTS ${THRIFT_COMPILER_ROOT} ${THRIFT_ROOT}/compiler/cpp/bin ${THRIFT_ROOT}/bin ${THRIFT_ROOT}/bin/Release /usr/local /opt/local PATH_SUFFIXES bin bin64)

   exec_program(${THRIFT_COMPILER}
                  ARGS -version 
                  OUTPUT_VARIABLE __thrift_OUT 
                  RETURN_VALUE THRIFT_RETURN)
   message( STATUS "Thrift compiler version: ${__thrift_OUT}" )
```

Comment: Ok, yes I see, cmake just generates the visual studio project files. Then after I set Project1 as my start project of the solution, building it should create an executable, right?

Comment: You have a solution with 1 or more projects inside. Each project could be either exe or lib, If your project is exe than you are able to build it and create exe. Later on you can run it...