# Creating Visual Studio Project from CMake, Visual studio does not find executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

Basically, I've got the same question as in
[How to configure CMake so that the generated Visual Studio project finds the executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55418401/how-to-configure-cmake-so-that-the-generated-visual-studio-project-finds-the-exe). None of the answers there worked for me.

I have a CMake project, and I just want to create a Visual Studio 2019 Project from it:

- So I just run `cmake .` from the root directory.
- Then I have a *.sln file in my root directory.
- After opening it with Visual Studio 2019, I press the "Local Widows Debugger" button, it compiles successfully but then the IDE complains with:

  ```
  Unable to start program 'C:\Users...\x64\Debug\ALL_BUILD'. The system is unable to find the specified file.
  ```

Using travis everything compiles fine, too: https://travis-ci.com/Necktschnagge/markov_chain_analyzer/builds/144941090

You can see the code here: https://github.com/Necktschnagge/markov_chain_analyzer/tree/old

What do I need to do so that CMake creates a VS solution, that is well-configured so that I can run the debugger?

Comment: Modern visual studio versions have direct integration for CMake: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019, so you can bypass all this now.

Comment: You don't start the "all_build" project usually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you create a Visual Studio solution with CMake, it automatically sets the Startup Project to `ALL_BUILD`. This is a CMake pre-defined target, which builds *all* of the projects in the solution. It is **not** a project containing an executable that can be debugged.

You must change the Startup Project in your **Solution Explorer** to one of your executable projects before debugging. You can do this by right-clicking on the project you want to debug, and selecting **Set as Startup Project**. There are some more instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#debugging-cmake-projects) if you're using VS with CMake integration.

You can also tell CMake to set a *different* Startup Project by default when building CMake from scratch, using [`VS_STARTUP_PROJECT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/VS_STARTUP_PROJECT.html). Put something like this in your top-level CMake file:

```
set_property(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT MyExeTarget)
```

Now, CMake will set `MyExeTarget` as the Startup Project in Visual Studio, instead of `ALL_BUILD`.